# Error installing Ruby on a Mac using RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I am completely new to Ruby, and I am having issues installing it on my Mac running Mountain Lion OS... any help would be great!!!

I have followed a tutorial, and I have installed GIT, curl and RVM. Next step is installing Ruby, which I tried but i got the following error

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
It is not possible to build movable binaries for rubies 1.8-1.9.2, but you can do it for your system only.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing macports............
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_install_port',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/mikelgainza/.rvm/log/1388506081_ruby-1.9.2-p320/port_install.log
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking objc/objc.h usability... yes
checking objc/objc.h presence... yes
checking for objc/objc.h... yes
checking if linking libobjc requires pthreads... no
checking for Apple Objective-C runtime... yes
checking for GNU Objective C runtime... no
configure: Using Apple Objective-C runtime
checking for Apple Foundation library... no
configure: WARNING: GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_ROOT is not defined in your environment, preventing the use of GNUstep's Foundation library
configure: error: Could not find a working Foundation implementation
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I also tried to install 2.1.0 . It finds the remote but then it gives some errors

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing macports............
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_install_port',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/mikelgainza/.rvm/log/1388512995_ruby-2.1.0/port_install.log
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking objc/objc.h usability... yes
checking objc/objc.h presence... yes
checking for objc/objc.h... yes
checking if linking libobjc requires pthreads... no
checking for Apple Objective-C runtime... yes
checking for GNU Objective C runtime... no
configure: Using Apple Objective-C runtime
checking for Apple Foundation library... no
configure: WARNING: GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_ROOT is not defined in your environment, preventing the use of GNUstep's Foundation library
configure: error: Could not find a working Foundation implementation
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but can you confirm that you actually have the development tools installed? Try running `gcc` on the command line and see if it works. If not, you'll need to download the Mac development tools from Apple's developer site.

Comment: Do you have installed Xcode?

Comment: I had gcc, but not xcode. I have xcode now but same error. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to install the Apple Developers Toolkit (`XCode`) from the Mac App Store (it's free)

Once that's installed, you'll need to install the CLI command line utilities by running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then try your install again, and it should work for you.

Additionally, you may want to install the latest version of Ruby, which at the time of this writing is `2.1.0` (via `rvm install 2.1.0`)

Finally, if you haven't already, I would recommend installing `homebrew` as well, as this has the added benefit of checking your runtime environment for errors (via `brew doctor`).  You can find instructions here:  http://brew.sh/

Good luck!

Comment: technically the latest version is `ruby-2.1`

Comment: Whoops, missed the release announcement.  Thanks @Doon :)

Comment: OK. I was not aware that you needed Xcode to use Ruby. I have gcc installed on the mac and i thought that would be enough.  thanks

Comment: Hi donovan, i have installed xcode but I am getting the same error as before. I have updated my question with the error I get when running **rvm install 2.1.0**

Comment: Also, the command **xcode-select --install** did not seem to work for me. In case it helps, when I do **xcode-select -version** I get **xcode-select version 2003**

Comment: @mga you don't need Xcode for Ruby, per se, but you do need the GCC Compiler (which is part of the command line tools) to install most things via homebrew.

Comment: @mga also, 2.1.0 was released on 12/25, so it may not have made it into the RVM build config yet (it's not in rbenv yet either).  So, for now, install 2.0.0 and upgrade to 2.1 later.

Comment: @mgs This is the version I have, `xcode-select version 2333`, so make sure you've gotten the lastest version of XCode from the _App Store_.

Comment: @Donovan latest rvm has 2.1. looks like command-line tools not installed is the current error

Comment: @Donovan. I have installed the CL tools from the XCode preferences and  i could install Ruby after that.  Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have come across to similar problem

```
➜  ~ rvm install 2.3.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system - please wait
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.3.0',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/admin/.rvm/log/1481339734_ruby-2.3.0/update_system.log
+rvm_error:2> rvm_pretty_print stderr
+rvm_pretty_print:2> case auto (0|no)
+rvm_pretty_print:2> case auto (1|auto)
+rvm_pretty_print:7> case xterm-256color (dumb|unknown)
+rvm_pretty_print:10> case stderr (stdout)
+rvm_pretty_print:10> case stderr (stderr)
+rvm_pretty_print:12> [[ -t 2 ]]
+rvm_pretty_print:12> return 1
+rvm_error:4> printf %b 'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
+requirements_osx_brew_update_system:25> return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

As been told in [Jekyll's Doc](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/),
I install Xcode Command-Line Tools

> Installing Xcode Command-Line Tools
>   If you run into issues installing Jekyll's dependencies which make use of native extensions and are using macOS, you will need to install Xcode and the Command-Line Tools it ships with. Download them in  Preferences → Downloads → Components.
>   And after install xcode-select:

```
xcode-select --install
```

then I install ruby 2.3.0 successfully.

```
➜  ~ rvm install 2.3.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.0 - #downloading ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0 13.5M    0 32283    0     0   4495      0  0:52:35  0:00:07  0:52:28  6  1 13.5M    1  143k    0     0  17673      0  0:13:22  0:00:08  0:13:14 28  1 13.5M    1  255k    0     0  28487      0  0:08:17  0:00:09  0:08:08 53  2 13.5M    2  351k    0     0  35391      0  0:06:40  0:00:10  0:06:30 80  3 13.5M    3  436k    0     0  39080      0  0:06:02  0:00:11  0:05:51 89  3 13.5M    3  495k    0     0  41702      0  0:05:40  0:00:12  0:05:28 95  4 13.5M    4  564k    0     0  43882      0  0:05:23  0:00:13  0:05:10 88  4 13.5M    4  623k    0     0  44999      0  0:05:15  0:00:14  0:05:01 75  4 13.5M    4  684k    0     0  46202      0  0:05:07  0:00:15  0:04:52 68  5 13.5M    5  735k    0     0  46462      0  0:05:05  0:00:16  0:04:49 64  5 13.5M    5  804k    0     0  47975      0  0:04:55  0:00:17  0:04:38 63  6 13.5M    6  879k    0     0  47817      0  0:04:56  0:00:18  0:04:38 56  6 13.5M    6  895k    0     0  47642      0  0:04:57  0:00:19  0:04:38 55  6 13.5M    6  948k    0     0  48109      0  0:04:54  0:00:20  0:04:34 53  7 13.5M    7  975k    0     0  47097      0  0:05:01  0:00:21  0:04:40 49  7 13.5M    7 1023k    0     0  47044      0  0:05:01  0:00:22  0:04:39 43  7 13.5M    7 1068k    0     0  47241      0  0:05:00  0:00:23  0:04:37 44  8 13.5M    8 1119k    0     0  47383      0  0:04:59  0:00:24  0:04:35 46  8 13.5M    8 1191k    0     0  48443      0  0:04:52  0:00:25  0:04:27 49  9 13.5M    9 1263k    0     0  49386      0  0:04:47  0:00:26  0:04:21 59  9 13.5M    9 1375k    0     0  51833      0  0:04:33  0:00:27  0:04:06 73 11 13.5M   11 1551k    0     0  56396      0  0:04:11  0:00:28  0:03:43 98 12 13.5M   12 1711k    0     0  59078      0  0:04:00  0:00:29  0:03:31  1 13 13.5M   13 1855k    0     0  62986      0  0:03:45  0:00:30  0:03:15  1 14 13.5M   14 1983k    0     0  65162      0  0:03:37  0:00:31  0:03:06  1 15 13.5M   15 2079k    0     0  66197      0  0:03:34  0:00:32  0:03:02  1 15 13.5M   15 2191k    0     0  67639      0  0:03:29  0:00:33  0:02:56  1 16 13.5M   16 2303k    0     0  69036      0  0:03:25  0:00:34  0:02:51  1 17 13.5M   17 2402k    0     0  69928      0  0:03:22  0:00:35  0:02:47  1 18 13.5M   18 2495k    0     0  70618      0  0:03:20  0:00:36  0:02:44  1 18 13.5M   18 2602k    0     0  71652      0  0:03:17  0:00:37  0:02:40  1 19 13.5M   19 2703k    0     0  72495      0  0:03:15  0:00:38  0:02:37  1 20 13.5M   20 2794k    0     0  72980      0  0:03:14  0:00:39  0:02:35 99 20 13.5M   20 2847k    0     0  72375      0  0:03:16  0:00:40  0:02:36 89 21 13.5M   21 2927k    0     0  72822      0  0:03:14  0:00:41  0:02:33 88 21 13.5M   21 3007k    0     0  73038      0  0:03:14  0:00:42  0:02:32 83 22 13.5M   22 3103k    0     0  73612      0  0:03:12  0:00:43  0:02:29 82 22 13.5M   22 3183k    0     0  73797      0  0:03:12  0:00:44  0:02:28 80 23 13.5M   23 3279k    0     0  74314      0  0:03:10  0:00:45  0:02:25 90 24 13.5M   24 3407k    0     0  75558      0  0:03:07  0:00:46  0:02:21 98 25 13.5M   25 3519k    0     0  76375      0  0:03:05  0:00:47  0:02:18  1 25 13.5M   25 3599k    0     0  76494      0  0:03:05  0:00:48  0:02:17    26 13.5M   26 3679k    0     0  76602      0  0:03:05  0:00:49  0:02:16    27 13.5M   27 3759k    0     0  76669      0  0:03:05  0:00:50  0:02:15 97 27 13.5M   27 3839k    0     0  76825      0  0:03:04  0:00:51  0:02:13 88 28 13.5M   28 3887k    0     0  76282      0  0:03:05  0:00:52  0:02:13 75 28 13.5M   28 3999k    0     0  77020      0  0:03:04  0:00:53  0:02:11 82 29 13.5M   29 4063k    0     0  76776      0  0:03:04  0:00:54  0:02:10 78 29 13.5M   29 4111k    0     0  75849      0  0:03:07  0:00:55  0:02:12 68 30 13.5M   30 4159k    0     0  75808      0  0:03:07  0:00:56  0:02:11 65 30 13.5M   30 4207k    0     0  75343      0  0:03:08  0:00:57  0:02:11 65 30 13.5M   30 4239k    0     0  74601      0  0:03:10  0:00:58  0:02:12 48 30 13.5M   30 4287k    0     0  74154      0  0:03:11  0:00:59  0:02:12 45 31 13.5M   31 4319k    0     0  73287      0  0:03:13  0:01:00  0:02:13 43 31 13.5M   31 4351k    0     0  72825      0  0:03:14  0:01:01  0:02:13 39 31 13.5M   31 4383k    0     0  72115      0  0:03:16  0:01:02  0:02:14 35 31 13.5M   31 4399k    0     0  71294      0  0:03:18  0:01:03  0:02:15 32 31 13.5M   31 4415k    0     0  70378      0  0:03:21  0:01:04  0:02:17 26 32 13.5M   32 4447k    0     0  69827      0  0:03:23  0:01:05  0:02:18 26 32 13.5M   32 4479k    0     0  69306      0  0:03:24  0:01:06  0:02:18 26 32 13.5M   32 4543k    0     0  69239      0  0:03:24  0:01:07  0:02:17 33 33 13.5M   33 4639k    0     0  69685      0  0:03:23  0:01:08  0:02:15 49 34 13.5M   34 4815k    0     0  71290      0  0:03:18  0:01:09  0:02:09 83 36 13.5M   36 5007k    0     0  72688      0  0:03:15  0:01:10  0:02:05  1 37 13.5M   37 5167k    0     0  74004      0  0:03:11  0:01:11  0:02:00  1 38 13.5M   38 5295k    0     0  74998      0  0:03:09  0:01:12  0:01:57  1 38 13.5M   38 5383k    0     0  74963      0  0:03:09  0:01:13  0:01:56  1 39 13.5M   39 5487k    0     0  75742      0  0:03:07  0:01:14  0:01:53  1 40 13.5M   40 5594k    0     0  76197      0  0:03:06  0:01:15  0:01:51  1 41 13.5M   41 5695k    0     0  76553      0  0:03:05  0:01:16  0:01:49  1 41 13.5M   41 5807k    0     0  77066      0  0:03:04  0:01:17  0:01:47  1 42 13.5M   42 5935k    0     0  77757      0  0:03:02  0:01:18  0:01:44  1 43 13.5M   43 6079k    0     0  78637      0  0:03:00  0:01:19  0:01:41  1 44 13.5M   44 6223k    0     0  79253      0  0:02:58  0:01:20  0:01:38  1 46 13.5M   46 6399k    0     0  80726      0  0:02:55  0:01:21  0:01:34  1 47 13.5M   47 6559k    0     0  81744      0  0:02:53  0:01:22  0:01:31  1 48 13.5M   48 6722k    0     0  82764      0  0:02:51  0:01:23  0:01:28  1 49 13.5M   49 6831k    0     0  83107      0  0:02:50  0:01:24  0:01:26  1 50 13.5M   50 6927k    0     0  83273      0  0:02:50  0:01:25  0:01:25  1 50 13.5M   50 7023k    0     0  83450      0  0:02:49  0:01:26  0:01:23  1 51 13.5M   51 7135k    0     0  83804      0  0:02:49  0:01:27  0:01:22  1 52 13.5M   52 7231k    0     0  83958      0  0:02:48  0:01:28  0:01:20  1 53 13.5M   53 7343k    0     0  84334      0  0:02:48  0:01:29  0:01:19  1 53 13.5M   53 7479k    0     0  84938      0  0:02:47  0:01:30  0:01:17  1 54 13.5M   54 7599k    0     0  85342      0  0:02:46  0:01:31  0:01:15  1 55 13.5M   55 7695k    0     0  85379      0  0:02:46  0:01:32  0:01:14  1 56 13.5M   56 7823k    0     0  85975      0  0:02:44  0:01:33  0:01:11  1 57 13.5M   57 7935k    0     0  86290      0  0:02:44  0:01:34  0:01:10  1 58 13.5M   58 8055k    0     0  86671      0  0:02:43  0:01:35  0:01:08  1 59 13.5M   59 8175k    0     0  86628      0  0:02:43  0:01:36  0:01:07  1 59 13.5M   59 8234k    0     0  86396      0  0:02:44  0:01:37  0:01:07  1 59 13.5M   59 8287k    0     0  86436      0  0:02:44  0:01:38  0:01:06 95 60 13.5M   60 8351k    0     0  86214      0  0:02:44  0:01:39  0:01:05 84 60 13.5M   60 8399k    0     0  85853      0  0:02:45  0:01:40  0:01:05 70 61 13.5M   61 8463k    0     0  85643      0  0:02:45  0:01:41  0:01:04 64 61 13.5M   61 8511k    0     0  85280      0  0:02:46  0:01:42  0:01:04 61 61 13.5M   61 8575k    0     0  84797      0  0:02:47  0:01:43  0:01:04 54 62 13.5M   62 8620k    0     0  84728      0  0:02:47  0:01:44  0:01:03 55 62 13.5M   62 8655k    0     0  84260      0  0:02:48  0:01:45  0:01:03 52 62 13.5M   62 8703k    0     0  83934      0  0:02:49  0:01:46  0:01:03 49 63 13.5M   63 8751k    0     0  83619      0  0:02:49  0:01:47  0:01:02 49 63 13.5M   63 8820k    0     0  83499      0  0:02:49  0:01:48  0:01:01 54 64 13.5M   64 8879k    0     0  83277      0  0:02:50  0:01:49  0:01:01 52 64 13.5M   64 8975k    0     0  83237      0  0:02:50  0:01:50  0:01:00 62 65 13.5M   65 9103k    0     0  83823      0  0:02:49  0:01:51  0:00:58 81 66 13.5M   66 9215k    0     0  84123      0  0:02:48  0:01:52  0:00:56 94 67 13.5M   67 9311k    0     0  84196      0  0:02:48  0:01:53  0:00:55 99 67 13.5M   67 9383k    0     0  84155      0  0:02:48  0:01:54  0:00:54  1 69 13.5M   69 9562k    0     0  85022      0  0:02:46  0:01:55  0:00:51  1 69 13.5M   69 9647k    0     0  85034      0  0:02:46  0:01:56  0:00:50  1 70 13.5M   70 9743k    0     0  85136      0  0:02:46  0:01:57  0:00:49  1 70 13.5M   70 9807k    0     0  84892      0  0:02:47  0:01:58  0:00:49    71 13.5M   71 9871k    0     0  84803      0  0:02:47  0:01:59  0:00:48 99 71 13.5M   71 9951k    0     0  84732      0  0:02:47  0:02:00  0:00:47 78 72 13.5M   72  9.7M    0     0  84620      0  0:02:47  0:02:01  0:00:46 75 72 13.5M   72  9.8M    0     0  84319      0  0:02:48  0:02:02  0:00:46 65 73 13.5M   73  9.9M    0     0  84331      0  0:02:48  0:02:03  0:00:45 70 73 13.5M   73  9.9M    0     0  84179      0  0:02:48  0:02:04  0:00:44 69 74 13.5M   74 10.0M    0     0  84134      0  0:02:48  0:02:05  0:00:43 69 74 13.5M   74 10.1M    0     0  84139      0  0:02:48  0:02:06  0:00:42 72 75 13.5M   75 10.1M    0     0  83940      0  0:02:48  0:02:07  0:00:41 74 75 13.5M   75 10.2M    0     0  83849      0  0:02:49  0:02:08  0:00:41 71 76 13.5M   76 10.3M    0     0  83963      0  0:02:48  0:02:09  0:00:39 78 77 13.5M   77 10.4M    0     0  83941      0  0:02:48  0:02:10  0:00:38 79 77 13.5M   77 10.5M    0     0  84059      0  0:02:48  0:02:11  0:00:37 82 78 13.5M   78 10.6M    0     0  84159      0  0:02:48  0:02:12  0:00:36 89 79 13.5M   79 10.7M    0     0  84391      0  0:02:48  0:02:13  0:00:35 98 80 13.5M   80 10.8M    0     0  84570      0  0:02:47  0:02:14  0:00:33 98 81 13.5M   81 10.9M    0     0  85208      0  0:02:46  0:02:15  0:00:31  1 82 13.5M   82 11.1M    0     0  85664      0  0:02:45  0:02:16  0:00:29  1 83 13.5M   83 11.2M    0     0  86230      0  0:02:44  0:02:17  0:00:27  1 84 13.5M   84 11.4M    0     0  86908      0  0:02:43  0:02:18  0:00:25  1 85 13.5M   85 11.6M    0     0  87583      0  0:02:41  0:02:19  0:00:22  1 86 13.5M   86 11.7M    0     0  87985      0  0:02:41  0:02:20  0:00:21  1 87 13.5M   87 11.8M    0     0  87953      0  0:02:41  0:02:21  0:00:20  1 88 13.5M   88 11.9M    0     0  88270      0  0:02:40  0:02:22  0:00:18  1 89 13.5M   89 12.0M    0     0  88200      0  0:02:40  0:02:23  0:00:17  1 89 13.5M   89 12.1M    0     0  88115      0  0:02:40  0:02:24  0:00:16  1 89 13.5M   89 12.1M    0     0  87903      0  0:02:41  0:02:25  0:00:16 85 90 13.5M   90 12.2M    0     0  87757      0  0:02:41  0:02:26  0:00:15 82 90 13.5M   90 12.3M    0     0  87450      0  0:02:42  0:02:27  0:00:15 65 91 13.5M   91 12.3M    0     0  87557      0  0:02:42  0:02:28  0:00:14 69 91 13.5M   91 12.4M    0     0  87413      0  0:02:42  0:02:29  0:00:13 67 92 13.5M   92 12.5M    0     0  87388      0  0:02:42  0:02:30  0:00:12 72 93 13.5M   93 12.5M    0     0  87348      0  0:02:42  0:02:31  0:00:11 75 93 13.5M   93 12.6M    0     0  87195      0  0:02:42  0:02:32  0:00:10 79 94 13.5M   94 12.7M    0     0  87167      0  0:02:42  0:02:33  0:00:09 75 94 13.5M   94 12.8M    0     0  87134      0  0:02:42  0:02:34  0:00:08 78 95 13.5M   95 12.8M    0     0  87050      0  0:02:42  0:02:35  0:00:07 76 95 13.5M   95 12.9M    0     0  86859      0  0:02:43  0:02:36  0:00:07 72 96 13.5M   96 12.9M    0     0  86694      0  0:02:43  0:02:37  0:00:06 71 96 13.5M   96 13.0M    0     0  86546      0  0:02:43  0:02:38  0:00:05 67 96 13.5M   96 13.1M    0     0  86347      0  0:02:44  0:02:39  0:00:05 62 97 13.5M   97 13.1M    0     0  86325      0  0:02:44  0:02:40  0:00:04 63 98 13.5M   98 13.2M    0     0  86303      0  0:02:44  0:02:41  0:00:03 68 99 13.5M   99 13.4M    0     0  86680      0  0:02:43  0:02:42  0:00:01 86100 13.5M  100 13.5M    0     0  87104      0  0:02:42  0:02:42 --:--:--  103k
ruby-2.3.0 - #extracting ruby-2.3.0 to /Users/admin/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0 - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #compiling - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #installing - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #making binaries executable - please wait
Installed rubygems 2.5.1 is newer than 2.4.8 provided with installed ruby, skipping installation, use --force to force installation.
ruby-2.3.0 - #gemset created /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
ruby-2.3.0 - #importing gemset /Users/admin/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #generating global wrappers - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #gemset created /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
ruby-2.3.0 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/admin/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.3.0 - #generating default wrappers - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-2.3.0 - #complete
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.5.1',
please read /home/ivliev/.rvm/log/1525444837_ruby-2.5.1/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

decision:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

delete the falling packages, and then run it again

look at the available packages

```
rvm list known
```

if necessary there is no. update package list

```
rvm get master
```

install the desired ruby

```
rvm install "ruby-2.5.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error - for me it was a problem with Homebrew - the last lines of the command logs said:

```
++ printf %b 'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'
```

So then I ran `brew update` which then gave me another error message with instructions on how to fix it. After I followed brew's instructions I was able to install Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

running:

```
rvm autolibs read-only;
rvm install x.x.x
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.